# How to save JSONObject to json file in UTF8 encoding Rad Studio/Delphi

Tags: json, delphi, pascal, rad-studio

I use Rad studio 11. I read information from json file (file is UTF8 encoded) and convert to jsonobject.
Then I make changes to this jsonobject and want to save to json file. The information is successfully written to the file, but the file has the Windows-1251 encoding. What needs to be done to make the file encoding UTF8? It's need me because json file include russian symbols (in Windows-1251 encoding it's looking like '?').

I read from a file like this:

```
var inputfile:TextFile;
str:string;
...
if OpenDialog1.Execute then  begin
  AssignFile(inputfile, OpenDialog1.FileName);
  reset(inputfile);

  while not Eof(inputfile) do
  begin
    ReadLn(inputfile, str);
    str1 := str1+UTF8ToANSI(str);
  end;

  closefile(inputfile);
end;
```

I convert to Jsonobject like this:

```
LJsonObj:=TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(str1) as TJSONobject;
```

Trying to save JsonObject like this:

```
var   
  listStr: TStringList;
  Size: Integer;
  I: Integer;
  
...
  
  Size := Form3.LJsonObj.Count;
  liststr := TStringList.Create;

  try
    listStr.Add('{');

    if Size > 0 then
      listStr.Add(LJsonObj.Get(0).ToString);
   
    showmessage(LJsonObj.Get(0).ToString);

    for I := 1 to Size - 1 do
    begin
      listStr.Add(',');
      listStr.Add(ANSITOUTF8(LJsonObj.Get(I).ToString));
    end;

    listStr.Add('}');
    // Form1.filepath-is path of file,form1.filename-name of file without file extension 
    listStr.SaveToFile(Form1.filepath+'\'+form1.filename+'.json');
  finally
    listStr.Free;
  end;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to loop over the JSONObject. Just use:

```
TFile.WriteAllBytes(Form1.filepath+'\'+form1.filename+'.json',TEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(LJsonObj.ToJSON))
```

Comment: OH,Yea,It's working,thank you:)

Comment: Why use `TFile.WriteAllBytes()` and not `TFile.WriteAllText()`? `TFile.WriteAllText(Form1.filepath+'\'+form1.filename+'.json', LJsonObj.ToJSON, TEncoding.UTF8);`

Comment: Tomayto - Tomarto :-). One or the other is fine by me...

Answer (score 7):

Why are you reading the file using old-style Pascal file I/O? And why are you converting between UTF-8 and *ANSI*?  You are using a Unicode version of Delphi, you should not be dealing with ANSI at all.

In any case:

- When reading the file, consider using `TStringList.LoadFromFile()` or `TFile.ReadAllText()` instead. Both allow you to specify UTF-8 as the source encoding.
- When writing the file, consider using `TStringList.SaveToFile()` or `TFile.WriteAllText()` instead.  Both allow you to specify UTF-8 as the target encoding.

For example:

```pascal
var
  inputfile: TStringList;
  str1: string;
  ...
begin
  ...
  inputfile := TStringList.Create;
  try
    inputfile.LoadFromFile(OpenDialog1.FileName, TEncoding.UTF8);
    str1 := inputfile.Text;
  finally
    inputfile.Free;
  end;
  ...
end;

...

var   
  listStr: TStringList;
  ...
begin
  ...
  listStr.SaveToFile(Form1.filepath + '\' + form1.filename + '.json', TEncoding.UTF8);
  ...
end;
```

```pascal
var
  str1: string;
  ...
begin
  ...
  str1 := TFile.ReadAllText(OpenDialog1.FileName, TEncoding.UTF8);
  ...
end;

...

var
  listStr: TStringList;
  ...
begin
  ...
  TFile.WriteAllText(listStr.Text, TEncoding.UTF8);
  ...
end;
```

Note that you don't really need to use a `TStringList` to build up JSON syntax manually.  `TJSONObject` has `ToString()` and `ToJSON()` methods to handle that for you.  But, if you really want to build up your own JSON syntax manually, consider using `TJSONObjectBuilder` or `TJsonTextWriter` for that purpose instead.